# Is there any way to get firebase Auth UID without login?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

What i want to know is without login get Auth User UID from firebase 
that already registered user

I already read firebase document but all the explain focus on when user logged only at that time  can get UID...

but i just want to get UID and user email address without login situation
Is there any way?

Comment: If you don't know the UID nor the email address of the user, what **do** you know of them? In other words: given all the users that are registered with Firebase, how do you know which one you want to display?

Comment: Excepet UID, know everything

Comment: @TTimfirst did you try my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there is no way using firebase authentication to retrieve the `uid` or `email` is the user is currently not logged in.

The only other way to actually retrieve them, is to use firebase database. So, when the user registers in your application, you also send the data of the user to the database and then you will be able to retrieve the data later on even if he is not logged in.

For example (on register) you can send this data to the database:

```
users
    userId
       email : email_here
       name  : name_here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

You can create the user via the Admin SDK if you know the user's credentials. You can also lookup an existing user's information by email or uid with the Admin SDK.

Learn more about this from the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a trick to do this. Though this is not an optimal solution.

One thing you have to remember that, **"There is no way to get a UID without login".**

1. Create a dummy user from your backend with a dummy email and password.
2. Send the email and password from the backend to your client-side app. You can always hash the password if you want to give an extra security layer.
3. Now call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function from firebase SDK and provide email and password which came from the backend.
4. The user is already registered in the backend, so now you can get the `UID` from your client app.

Comment: So far this has been the only solution that I am thinking of doing, however it looks like there would be some extra work to be done if a user would later on in the future decide to change his/her password.

Answer (score 0):

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                
                Log.d("userstatus","user id is "+user.getUid());
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
               
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: For more information go through the official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

Comment: Pease add an explanation directly here in the answer. Linking is not considered giving the information here, at least summarise. Also (when ignoring the link, which many users actually do here) this is a code-only answer. That also would be remedied with an explanation. Lastly, answering with explained code, pointing out the mechanisms, would help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a platform for finding programmers for doing unpaid programming work.